# specifying connection on ESP8266 with AP and STA modes

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, access-point

I want to try to set up an ESP8266 (using the Arduino IDE) to occasionally connect to a wifi SSID to send telemetry back. I also would really like to be able to have it running a softAP for configuration/settings purposes. (i.e. so if you want to change internal settings in your code, you can connect directly to the device to access a web form to do so)

The problem is, I am not 100% sure how I know which is which when making an outgoing telemetry json query. I want it to go out on the STATION mode connection. Presumably in most cases the AP mode won't be connected, but there may be rare instances where both are connected at the same time. Thus how do I tell the device to specifically use the STA side of things when it needs to send data back over the internet?

I can't even seem to find any specific examples to ask if one or the other is connected. (you can poll WiFi.status() but - which one is it reporting?)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you don't because the AP has no internet connection, so it won't even try...

Comment: thanks. I guessed as much, but wasn't sure and was a long way from getting any code working that was even capable of doing both at once.